# SQL Query for conditionally moving data from two tables into another

Tags: sql, database, toad

I have three tables, with following columns

```
Table: raw_data
Columns: first_name, email, club_name

Table: contacts
Columns: first_name, email, club_id

Table: clubs
Columns: club_id, club_name
```

Currently Data is present in raw_data table, I want to insert data into contacts table as follows

```
first_name: (from raw_data)
email: (from raw_data)
club_id: (compare club_name in clubs table and get club_id)
```

I am able to insert name and email data but need help for club_id comparison

My current query is as follows

```
INSERT INTO contacts (first_name,email)
SELECT first_name,email
FROM raw_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a JOIN:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (first_name, email, club_id)
   SELECT r.first_name, r.email, c.club_id
     FROM raw_data r JOIN clubs c ON c.club_name = r.club_name;
```